# Excel formula to concatenate Average with Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel I have a range on which I need to calculate average and show the result in a new cell  in this format:

```
38.2% (Avg)
```

I tried to use this formula

```
=CONCATENATE(AVERAGE(Y7:Y14), " (Avg)")
```

But this formula shows the result this way:

```
.38264782356378563576 (Avg)
```

How can I restrict the number to 2 decimal places and put the % symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use custom formatting which serves the purpose of displaying *and* keeping the value as a number (on which you can perform further calculations with ease):

[image]

The formatting is:

```
00.0% "(Avg)"
```

Or if you don't want to get keep it as number, you can always do:

```
=TEXT(AVERAGE(Y7:Y14),"00.0% ""(Avg)""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the number with 100, then use `ROUND()` on this number to round up to the amount of digits you require (1) and change your string `(Avg)` to `% (Avg)`.

```
=CONCATENATE(ROUND(100*AVERAGE(Y7:Y14), 1), "% (Avg)")
```